# Not all e-mails being sent using SmtpClient in an ASP.NET MVC getting delivered. Why? How to resolve?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, smtpclient

Here is the set-up:

1. I have a Notifications controller that is called from task scheduler 1x/day
2. The action method pulls upwards of 300 addresses, loops thru them and uses the SmtpClient class to send an individual e-mail to each recepient.

From what I can tell the process runs fine with no exceptions ... *except* that not all e-mails are being delivered.  Anyone have any ideas on what is going on and how to resolve?

Here is the code:

```
foreach (var emp in division.Users)
{
    var fromAddress = "myfromaddress";
    var mailServer = "mymailserver";

    var toEmail = emp.EmailAddress;

    var message = new MailMessage(fromAddress, toEmail)
                    {
                        Subject = subject,
                        Body = "<body style='font:normal 13px tahoma,arial,helvetica;'>" + body + "</body>",
                        IsBodyHtml = true
                    };

    var client = new SmtpClient(mailServer);
    client.Send(message);
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Adding a pause in between sending e-mails resolves the problem.  But why does this work? And is there a better way (e.g. using Async()) that would equally resolve the issue in a better way???

Updated code ...

```
foreach (var emp in division.Users)
{
    var fromAddress = "myfromaddress";
    var mailServer = "mymailserver";

    var toEmail = emp.EmailAddress;

    var message = new MailMessage(fromAddress, toEmail)
                    {
                        Subject = subject,
                        Body = "<body style='font:normal 13px tahoma,arial,helvetica;'>" + body + "</body>",
                        IsBodyHtml = true
                    };

    var client = new SmtpClient(mailServer);
    client.Send(message);

    Thread.Sleep(3000); // Wait 3s until sending next message
}
```

Comment: Are you sure about your SMTP server's functionality? Maybe try your code with Gmail would help you locate the problem. Also try logging with some logging tool, hope that helps.

Comment: Unfortunately, I suspect that there's nothing in your code you can change to fix this; it's likely is a server-config issue.  There are a **lot** of you hoops you have to jump through when setting up a bulk smtp server or your messages will be flagged as spam by many e-mail providers.  You should probably try a version of this question on serverfault instead.

Comment: Yes, I've verified that this works with smaller lists of e-mails (e.g. I just tested with sending out 20 e-mails in a loop ... no problem)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is a default timeout with the smtp client and default value is 100sec

[more info here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.timeout.aspx)

Comment: I don't think it is the timeout as it isn't taking anywhere close to 100s to send out an individual e-mail.

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly advice on using `SmtpClient.SendAsync()` as Send() is blocking.

I would check the logs of the SMTP server that you're sending to. Note: sending your own emails are more likely to end in Junk mail than using a trusted provider.

**Edit:** added sample SendAsync code

```
smtpClient.SendCompleted += smtpClient_SendCompleted;

static void smtpClient_SendCompleted(object sender, System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Error != null)
    {
        Log.ErrorFormat("Async Mail exception {0} :: {1}", 
            e.Error.GetType().Name, e.Error.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: How does this work in an MVC environment?  In other words, how do I determine success, failure, etc...?

Comment: @Fredou How so? All that needs to be changed is to call SendAsync and provide an event handler for the SendCompleted event...

Comment: @Fredou edited answer to include example for checking errors in async call

Comment: I'm still not sure how this works in an ASP.NET MVC environment where I have a controller (NotificationsController) with an action method (SendNotifications) that does this work.  As far as I'm aware, after the SendNotifications method completes, the instance of "NotificaitonsController" is garbage collected making it unavailable to receive the messages from Async, no?

Comment: I believe that since the the SmtpClient.SendCompleted will still be holding a reference to the event handler (defined in the NotificationsController) it should stick around until all have completed, with or without an error.

Comment: I'll have to test.  I do notice that if I pause in between sending mail (Thread.Sleep(3000) ... 3s) ... ALL of the emails are sent.  So I'm wondering if it has something to do with pounding the mailserver one right after another????

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163725.aspx and http://download.microsoft.com/download/4/1/9/4194800d-ba53-423b-a379-f668cb08502c/cs_sc-Asynchronous%20Email_cs.zip

Answer (score 0):

If you are not having any exceptions I'd check SPAM folders and email addresses. I'd also try sending an email manually from your outlook to one of the addresses that didn't recieve a message.

On a side note, unless you are using different mail servers, I think you can change this code to

```
var client = new SmtpClient(mailServer); 
var mailServer = "mymailserver";

foreach (var emp in division.Users) 
{ 
    var fromAddress = "myfromaddress"; 


    var toEmail = emp.EmailAddress; 

    var message = new MailMessage(fromAddress, toEmail) 
                    { 
                        Subject = subject, 
                        Body = "<body style='font:normal 13px tahoma,arial,helvetica;'>" + body + "</body>", 
                        IsBodyHtml = true 
                    }; 


    client.Send(message); 
}
```

You might also try SendAsync method of the SmtpClient class, like this:

```
// setup the callback method when the send finishes
client.SendCompleted += SendComplete; //new SendCompletedEventHandler(smtpSender_SendCompleted);

// send the email
client.SendAsync(message, null);



private void SendComplete(object sender, System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    // do stuff on complete
}
```

Comment: Nope ... junk, spam folders don't have the message either

Comment: I have a similar application using the SendAsync method and it sends 100s of emails without issues...

Comment: No, it is a windows service... but that should not make a difference since the code is mostly the same. Try using the Async method and then investigate the AsyncCompletedEventArgs object to see if any errors are happening.